# Low voltage security

Tags: esp32, voltage

I'm building a circuit with a GPS sensor and an esp32. My input voltage is designed to be 5V but I experienced some issues where people put lower charger in input (<4V). As a result my esp32 will boot but will functions erratically.
As I'm quite new with components and circuits, I was wondering if there was a way to ensure no current will go to my esp32 unless the input voltage is at least 5V?

Board being used: Espressif esp32 devkitc 4
https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/get-started/get-started-devkitc.html

Thanks for your help

Comment: What you are looking for is a power-on-reset generator. A workaround in software could be to wait some ms before initializing any peripheral device. How do you know your esp boots and **in which way** does it behave erratically? Usually the esp's brownout detector triggers a reboot when the voltage drops too far

Comment: As far as I can see, you can set the brownout detection to a higher value. Default is `CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_0` which is 2.4V. You can change it upto `CONFIG_BROWNOUT_DET_LVL_SEL_7` which is 2,74V. But I think the issue might be with the voltage regulator that converts the 5V down to 3.3V.